# Does Cordova's inAppBrowser plugin's "close" method remove all listeners?

Tags: cordova, inappbrowser

Does Cordova's inAppBrowser plugin's "close" method remove all listeners added to the window reference obtained from the "open" method, so I don't need to use removeEventListener?

Example:

```
const ref = cordova.inAppBrowser.open("https://www.google.it", "_blank");
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(){});
ref.addEventListener('exit', function(){});
ref.close();
```

I expect that the "exit" function executes, but after that all the listeners will be destroyed.